# Prove that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is decreasing and continuous, then there is a unique point $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\,f(c)=c$.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that if function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is decreasing and continuous, then there exists a unique point $c$ belonging to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\,f(c)=c$.

Can I start off with proving this is a monotonic function?

Comment: That it is monotonic is by hypothesis...

Comment: **Hint:** consider $g(x)=f(x)-x$ and try to use the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the line $y = x$. A decreasing and continuous function $f$ starts above this line and winds up below this line, passing the line exactly once.

This is not a proof, but does provide a hint what to look for. First argue that there is an $x_0$ for which $f(x_0) > x_0$. Then argue that there is an $x_1$ for which $f(x_1) < x_1$. After this, apply the intermediate value theorem to $g(x) := f(x) - x$ to show that there is a $c$ with $f(c) = c$. Finally, show unicity by assuming there is also $c' \neq c$ with $f(c') = c'$ and derive a contradiction.

Comment: The first two lines are very nice intuitive explanation. +1